# how to access ~/.vmc/crash folder on Cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

CFoundry::AppStopped: 305: Operation not permitted on a stopped app
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

Noobie on this so i would like to find out how to access this folder...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a text file, so try:

```
cat ~/.vmc/crash
```

Comment: Just to make this clear: this is a _local_ file, not a file on the Cloud Foundry remote end.