# vmc push Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, smtp, npm, cloud-foundry, nodemailer

I am trying to deploy this example to Cloud Foundry

https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/blob/master/examples/example_smtp.js

Here is what I did:

1. `npm install nodemailer`
2. Rename `example_smtp.js` to `app.js` and edit fields for right email credential
3. Tested `node app.js` locally and it works / email sent
4. `vmc push` and got below error

> Uploading mytestmailer... FAILED Upload failed. Try again with 'vmc
>   push'. Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory -
>   C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/.
>   vmc_hocmailer_files/node_modules/nodemailer/node_modules/simplesmtp/node_modules
>   /xoauth2/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-strea
>   m/node_modules/delayed-stream/test/integration/test-delayed-http-upload.js
>   For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

I search and found this thread to figure out what is in `~/.vmc/crash`

[how to access ~/.vmc/crash folder on Cloud foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743288/how-to-access-vmc-crash-folder-on-cloud-foundry)

But I am using **Windows** so I cannot find that crash file.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot this issue? Seem to be a simple deployment.

Comment: The log is probably in `%userprofile%/.vmc/crash`.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem ends up being a filename length limit; the filename is 272 bytes long (greater than 256 characters).

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks found it. But nothing useful there except the same error msg. The `path string/filename` is 272 characters. How to fix it now??

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you create a package.json file that specifies the dependencies of the application, in this case it should look something like this;

```
{
  "name": "node-mailer-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "*"
  }
}
```

With nothing but this and app.js in the folder, install the dependencies for the application with npm;

```
npm install
```

This should create a new 'node_modules' folder with the dependencies included inside.

Also, you need to change the first line of your app.js file so it reads;

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

I did it like this and it deployed ok, I got this message in the application log;

```
SMTP Configured
Sending Mail
Error occured
Invalid login - 535-5.7.1 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at
535 5.7.1 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 hr1sm24898342qeb.3 - gsmtp
```

BTW, when you send mail on mass through gMail, where each e-mail has the same content, gMail will eventually require you log in via the web interface before you can continue.

Comment: So within `node_modules\nodemailer` folder, there is already a package.json to specify all nodemailer's dependencies. I have to copy the content of that file to place it in my app.js folder? Because there is really no other dependencies beside `nodemailer` (this is just a simple Hello World)

Comment: I mean your application should have a package.json, specifying it's own dependencies (nodemailer). The package.json in my answer should be in the root of your application.